# Binomial - quick product calculation

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I have the following formula

$$\sum_{i=0}^nX^i\binom{\{b_1,...,b_n\}}{i}(-k+n-i)$$

where this binomial expression is e.g. for ${n=3}$ and ${i=2}$ equal to

$$\binom{\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}}{2} = b_1b_2 + b_1b_3 + b_2b_3$$

so full formula for `n=3` would be

$$b_1 b_2 b_3 X^3 (-k)+X^2 \left(b_1 b_2 (-k)-b_3 b_2 k-b_1 b_3 k+b_1 b_2+b_3 b_2+b_1 b_3\right)+X \left(b_1 (-k)-b_2 k-b_3 k+2 b_1+2 b_2+2
   b_3\right)-k+3=0$$

For small `n` and `i` it is easy to calculate this. But when I try to calculate for larger `n` values (say `n=40`), when `i` gets to value of around 8 it slows down a lot. What I currently do is generate all possible `i` combinations of `n` elements, and then sum up their product (as in above example for `n=3` and `i=2`).

Is there any way to calculate these values without generating all possible `i` combinations of `n` elements, and then summing up all of those combinations products?

**UPDATE**

Trying to calculate for $b_1=1;  b_2=2;  b_3=3$ I have:

$$\binom{\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}}{1} = b_1 + b_2 + b_3 = 1 + 2 + 3 = 6$$
$$\binom{\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}}{2} = b_1b_2 + b_1b_3 + b_2b_3 = 2 + 3 + 6 = 11$$
$$\binom{\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}}{3} = b_1b_2b_3 = 6$$

Using formulas from post below:

$$P_1(X)=(X-b_1) \Longrightarrow a_1^1=1; a_0^1=-1$$
$$P_2(X)=(X-b_2)P_1(X) \Longrightarrow a_2^2=1; a_1^2=a_0^1-(b_2a_1^1)=-3; a_0^2=-b_2(a_0^1)=2$$
$$P_3(X)=(X-b_3)P_2(X) \Longrightarrow a_3^3=1; a_2^3=a_1^2-(b_3a_2^2)=-6; a_1^3=a_0^2-(b_3a_1^2)=11; a_0^3=-b_3(a_0^2)=-6$$

so we have

$$\binom{\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}}{1} = (-1)^1a_2^3 = (-1)(-6) = 6$$
$$\binom{\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}}{2} = (-1)^2a_1^3 = (1)(11) = 11$$
$$\binom{\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}}{3} = (-1)^3a_0^3 = (-1)(-6) = 6$$

**UPDATE**

Related to last comment in accepted answer:

Using this expansion, I get:

$$(X-b_1)(X-b_2)(X-b_3) = X^3 + (-b_1-b_2-b_3)X^2 + (b_1b_2+b_1b_3+b_2b_3)X + (-b_1b_2b_3)$$

but what I actually use in my expression is:

$$(b_1b_2b_3)X^3+(b_1b_2+b_1b_3+b_2b_3)X^2+(b_1+b_2+b_3)X+1$$

so this procedure to get coefficients works, but then I need to flip them and use with different powers in my equation.

Because of that - not sure how to proceed with your last comment (to not need to calculate coefficients).

What I actually try to do is calculate this X (for `n=3`, where $b_1,b_2,b_3$ and $k$ are real positive numbers that are given):

$$\frac{1}{b_1+1} + \frac{1}{b_2+1} + \frac{1}{b_3+1} = 1$$
$$\frac{1}{(b_1*X+1)} + \frac{1}{(b_2*X+1)} + \frac{1}{(b_3*X+1)} = k$$

and when this equations are reduced, you get in the end:

$$b_1 b_2 b_3 X^3 (-k)+X^2 \left(b_1 b_2 (-k)-b_3 b_2 k-b_1 b_3 k+b_1 b_2+b_3 b_2+b_1 b_3\right)+X \left(b_1 (-k)-b_2 k-b_3 k+2 b_1+2 b_2+2
   b_3\right)-k+3=0$$

that is

$$X^3 (b_1 b_2 b_3) (-k)+X^2 \left(b_1 b_2+b_3 b_2+b_1 b_3\right) (-k+1) + X \left(b_1+b_2+b_3\right) (-k+2) + (-k+3) = 0$$

Comment: My post was completed. $a_0^2 = 2$. I guess you are not used with polynomial operation.

Comment: @Damien thanks. I don't know how I didn't see a_0^k yesterday. I just updated my question with sample for cubic. It seems all OK. Thanks!

Comment: I added $a_0^k$ during the night...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Vieta's formulas.

You need to calculate the coefficients of the polynomial, the roots of which are the $b_i$.

$$P(X) = (X-b_1)(X-b_2)\dots(X-b_n) = a_nX^n\dots+a_1X+a_0$$

Note that $a_n = 1$.

The $a_i$ can be calculated in a recursive way. Let us call $P_k(X)$ the polynomial corresponds to the first $k$ values $b_k$:

$$P_k(X) = (X-b_1)(X-b_2)\dots(X-b_k) = a^k_kX^k\dots+a^k_1X+a^k_0$$

We have

$$P_1(X) = (X-b_1) \implies \quad a^1_1 = 1\quad a^1_0= -b_1$$
$$P_{k}(X) = (X-b_k)P_{k-1}(X) \implies \quad a^k_k = 1\\ a^k_j= a^{k-1}_{j-1}-b_k a^{k-1}_{j}\;j=1..(k-1)\\a^k_0=-b_k a^{k-1}_0$$

Then the simple Vieta's formulas will directly give you the values you are looking for, from the $a_i$.

$$\binom{\{b_1,...,b_n\}}{i} = (-1)^{i} \frac{a_{n-i}}{a_n} = (-1)^{i} a_{n-i}$$

Global complexity is $O(n^2)$.

Note that if the goal is to calculate
$$\sum_{i=0}^nX^i\binom{\{b_1,...,b_n\}}{i}(-k+n-i)$$
you are not obliged to calculate the coefficients, and you can try to directly use the polynomial $P(X)$.

Comment: is this for finding roots, or for calculating coefficients. Since I have not problem with roots, but coefficients. Like I said in case `n=40` and `i=20` I would need to calculate sum of `1.378465288 E+11` products. This is problem I'm having.

Comment: I tried to complete my post. The roots are the $b_i$, you have them already. You have to calculate the $a_i$, recursively from the $b_i$

Comment: Thanks. I'll read more about Vieta's formulas now, to see if I can use them as you just said.

Comment: updated question with full formula for n=3. Could you please give me example for this case?

Comment: haha, tnx for help. I'm checking this Vieta's, but still cannot find how to...

Comment: this is only what I saw from wikipedia $\binom{\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}}{1} = -\frac{a_2}{a_3}$, $\binom{\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}}{2} = \frac{a_1}{a_3}$, $\binom{\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}}{3} = -\frac{a_0}{a_3}$, but still don't know how to get a_n without multiplying all of b coefs.

Comment: thanks a ton for explanation. I'm trying to calc. it now. Seems like there is some problem in j=1..(k-1), since above you have a_0, so I guess it goes j=0...(k-1). But if that is the case I don't have a_-1. I will try to post example now for n=3.

Comment: updated the question now.

Comment: Note that I just made a little correction this morning ($a_{n-i}$), and added a comment at the end

Comment: with this new update - you mean just to use for n=3 (X-b1)(X-b2)(X-b3) * (-k+3)(-k+2)(-k+1)?

Comment: Not exactly. I don't know where $k$ comes from. You have to manage the $(-1)^i$ (not difficult). And the factor $i$ in the sum corresponds to a derivation of a polynomial. No time to work at it now, but you have all the information. Vieta's formula are useful anyway. I don't know how you intend to use this formula. You may rely on what has been done anyway, as the result is correct and rather fast.

Comment: I will try to see now how directly to use P(X). Will post here if I manage to do anything :)

Comment: k is just external input value for which I'm trying to find 1 real root using Newton-Raphson method.

Comment: OK. Happy to have helped. Let me know if you find something interesting

Comment: if you get some time, you can check updated end of my question with actual problem I was trying to solve and how I got to that equation. Anyway, your solution with Vieta's works perfectly in my code now.

Comment: I just realized that I never needed to expand my equation. All I needed to do is to get derivative of that original function $\frac{1}{(b_1*X+1)} + \frac{1}{(b_2*X+1)} + \frac{1}{(b_3*X+1)} = k$ and find X from there using N-R method...

Comment: Effectively, it looks like a much simpler problem. I once read an advice in a maths books: when you get a solution of a problem, you better understand the problem and then thanks to this better understanding it is time for looking for a better/simpler solution